# Please tell me how to evaluate this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute the area of that portion of the conical surface $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ which lies between the
two planes $z = 0$ and $x + 2z = 3$.
Ans:$2\pi\sqrt{6}$.
Thank you.

Comment: Draw the area and use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: But here I am supposed to find surface area...could you please tell me the limit of integration?

Comment: Than you can use the formula: $\iint\limits_D \sqrt{1+z_{x}'^{2}+z_{y}'^{2}}dxdy$ where D is the projetction of given area to Oxy plane.

Answer (score 1):

The surface area is 
$$\iint\limits_A \sqrt{1+f_{x}^{2}+f_{y}^{2}}dxdy$$
where $A$ is the ellipse $3x^2+4y^2+6x-9=0$ (by solving both equations)and $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$[image]